# Copy into different cells everytime - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

Beginner in VBA. Trying to create that using a loop:
[image]

There are numbers in the orange cells, and they are doubled by numbers from 1-7 and the results are shown in different columns.

I tried to create a loop that does that without using the numbers in row 1. Wrote that code:

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim a(1 To 10)

For r = 3 To 6
    For c = 3 To 9
        For d = 1 To 7
            Range("A9").Value = d
            a(r) = Cells(r, 2).Value
            Cells(r, c).Value = a(r)
        Next
    Next
Next r
```

The formula in B3, for example, is A3*A9.
I prefer working with cells(r,c) and not range.

Right now, all blue columns are showing the result of the last number run into A9 by the loop:

[image]

Not sure how to make the loop copy different cells each time...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third loop isn't necessary here, you can offset by the negative value of the row + 1 to get the values you want to multiply by.

```
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As Long
d = 1
With ActiveSheet
    For r = 3 To 6
        For c = 3 To 9
            If d = 8 Then
                d = 1
            End If
            .cells(9, 1).value = d
            .Cells(r, c).Value = .Cells(r, 1).Value * d
            d = d + 1
        Next c
    Next r
End With
```

Alternatively this can be done with a simple formula:

```
=$A3*C$1
```

And drag that to the relevant cells.

Comment: Thanks. The example is a simplification of a more complex sheet I've got - in which A9 cell is important... I know the simple formula, trying to do that using VBA. Is there any possibility to do that while using For and looping A9?

Comment: I think that's what you are asking for?